# Get list of all custom users in template (Django)

Tags: python, django, templates, django-custom-user

I have defined a custom user model, which is working fine and all that. However, in a certain view I would like the user to list all registered users, but I can't seem to get that to work. I  was hoping to be able to access all users from the template that is used to render the view, but I don't know where to start.

This is what I've got so far - which works when using the original User model, but it doesn't work with my custom one.

## views.py

```
class UsersView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'customer/users/users.html'
```

## users.html

```
<h1>Users</h1>

<ul>
  {% for user in object_list %}
    <li class="user">{{ user }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

## urls.py

```
url(r'^customer/users/', views.UsersView.as_view(), name='users'),
```

## models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    """
    Abstraction of a user.

    first_name - The first name of the user
    last_name - The last name of the user
    email - The email and username of the user
    project - The project that the user is part of
    is_active- Determines if the user is active, i.e. is the user "alive"
    is_project_admin - Determines if the user has access to the project admin views
    is_superuser - Determines if the user has full access to the entire database. Usually not.

    This model is used to store information about users.
    """

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, help_text="The first name of the user.")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, help_text="The last name of the user.")
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        help_text="The email and username of the user. Required."
    )

    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, null=True, blank=True, help_text="The project that this user is part of.", related_name='users')

    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        default=True, 
        help_text="Determines whether the user is active or not. ",
        verbose_name="active"
    )
    is_project_admin = models.BooleanField(
        default=False, 
        help_text="Determines if the user has admin access in a project.",
        verbose_name="project admin"
    )
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(
        default=False, 
        help_text="CAUTION - enabling this gives the user full admin access and access to the entire database. Only for ArcCore admins.",
        verbose_name="superuser"
    )

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'

    def get_full_name(self):
        #If the full name is not specified, return email
        if self.first_name == "" and self.last_name == "":
            return self.email
        else:
            return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
    get_full_name.short_description = 'Name'

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a superuser?"
        return self.is_superuser
```

Please disregard any bad code in models.py, since I am new to both Python and Django and I haven't started refactoring yet.

Does anyone know how to list all my users in the tempate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try {{user.email}} in template instead of {{user}}?

Comment: @VenkateshBachu Yes, the problem is in accessing all users - when using for example {{ user }} outside the loop I get the email like i want. I just cant seem to access all users the right way.

Comment: can you update your question with view function

Comment: @VenkateshBachu added the view class.

Comment: did you add CustomUser model name in url?

Comment: @VenkateshBachu Updated question with url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with the below view function

```
class UsersView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'customer/users/users.html'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(UsersView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['object_list'] = CustomUser.objects.all()
        return context
```

Comment: Perhaps worth putting a [link to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how this code could ever have worked. Your view is a simple template view, and never does anything to get a list of users: that applies as much to the default User model as to your custom one.

You need to subclass [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#generic-views-of-objects) instead of TemplateView, and set the `model` attribute to your User class.

Comment: I thought about that, but I want the template to be able to do lots oof things and TemplateView seemed right.